# Spring security Pre authentication success handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a web app where you can login with form-login or you can be pre-authenticated and be logged in like that. Both method work well but I only can find way to use a success handler with the form-login using the authentication-success-handler-ref property.

My question is, how can I call the success handler "mySuccessHandler" for the PRE_AUTH_FILTER in my security-app-context? I would guess I can call it as a property or something under the PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, preauthAuthProvider or the custom-filter.

Just need to go to different pages if the user has the role Teacher or Student.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/ErrorPages/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Students/**" access="hasAnyRole('STUDENT, TEACHER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Teacher/**" access="hasRole('TEACHER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Login/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Js/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/Img/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" />
    <access-denied-handler
    <form-login
            username-parameter="idnumber"
            password-parameter="password" login-processing-url="/athuga_innskraningu"
            login-page='/login.jsp'
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
            always-use-default-target='true'
            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/utskra/" logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
</http>


<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="is.inna.rest.login.AuthenticationSuccess"/>
<beans:bean id="myAuthErrorHandler" class="is.inna.rest.login.AuthenticationFailure"/>
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<beans:bean name="myUserDetailsService" class="is.inna.rest.login.UserDetailServiceLogin" />
<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="is.inna.rest.login.UserDetailServicePreAuth" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceWrapper"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" class="is.inna.rest.login.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is to redirect user to different pages depending on the role. You can do this using authentication success handler also. Refer the sample [success handler](https://github.com/jeevan-patil/transbank/blob/master/src/main/java/com/transbank/online/handlers/AuthSuccessHandler.java) class I have written. You always have access to `Authentication` object in the overridden `onAuthenticationSuccess` method. You can get the authorities and role of logged in user and depending upon it, you can always redirect user to appropriate page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I made the success handler exactly like you. And added <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="my.path.AuthSuccessHandler" /> in my security-context.xml file. But the code in the success handler is never called, any idea why that is?

Comment: Yeah, you are calling authentication-success-handler-ref="authHandler" that uses SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler, but i need to know how to call that when I use the pre-auth filter.

Comment: Why calling handler before authentication is been done? It makes sense to redirect user to different pages only if it turns out to be a valid user. So using authentication success handler here is a right approach.